# How can I tell if my Wii Remote is counterfeit? (with pics)

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiimote

I bought a refurbished Wii and I felt the remotes were not performing as well as I remembered them. So I started looking up the net and it seems that counterfeit Wii remotes that look quite like the original are a "thing". I weighed them and they are 80g with the strap, which is indeed a bit light according to some sources. To make sure I opened one and it does not look like the pics I see from genuine Wii remotes. But just to make sure Nintendo has not changed the designed and I am looking at older pics only, could you guys weigh-in and tell me if I am right and these are knock-offs?

Thanks!

EDIT: I also see that the sensitivity setting for the sensor bar appears to do nothing when used with these remotes. Supposedly changing the sensitivity affects the IR sensitivity of the remote, but from min to max it makes no difference. I guess that's a way to tell a counterfeit, right?

[image: Wii Remote PCB]
[image: Wii Remote]

Edit 2: I contacted the seller and he did not debate at all, he told me he is sending two replacement remotes. Thanks for the answers, not sure which one I should "accept".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for validation on a particular users hardware authenticity. We are not Nintendo, so we can not tell you with a 100% guarantee if the controller is authentic or not. Perhaps you would be better seeking Nintendos input, through their support services?

Comment: Isn't it sort of the same as "how to spot a fake", but with an example attached?

Comment: @Timelord64 why does that make it off topic?

Comment: @Aequitas, because we are a Q and A site. We take questions it is possible to answer; We do not take questions it is impossible to answer. I do not believe that questions involving the internal mechanics or validity of a controller are on topic, past the "does it actually work with the console" point of call. As I said before, only Nintendo could tell 100%. The rest is just our speculation

Comment: @Timelord64 how is it not possible to answer? as a community of gamers i'd say there's quite a high chance that at least one person has a wiimote, all they have to do then is open it up as op has done and look to see if it kinda looks the same.

Comment: @Aequitas, but "kind of the same thing" means a different thing for a gamer, than it does for a hardware engineer. Ultimately, all you can do over the internet is say "it looks about right".

Comment: I would say this could be re-addressed to "how can I tell if my wii remote is counterfeit", asking for general solutions to determining obvious fakes. Does not stray off the original path all that much, but if the pictures are used as a reference instead of an absolute identification requirement, this becomes easier to answer in an absolute manner. Also, seeing as were addressing what to look for, and not what is wrong with OPs specific 'potential counterfeit', this would be more helpful to future users.

Comment: I renamed it. Also if what I notice about the sensitivity setting is correct, that would be one way to judge a counterfeit without actually opening it, which might be useful for others.

Comment: AFAIK when it comes to the sensitivity setting it actually just bumps up the brightness of the "sensor" bar LEDs. One way to test that out would be to grab your cell phone camera and point it at your sensor bar.

Comment: @WayneWerner That's not how the sensor bar works. It is just IR lights and there is no communication/control with the Wii. Otherwise the wireless 3rd party sensor bars would not work properly. The "sensor bar sensitivity" controls how sensitive the remote is to those lights. On the Wii U it is more correctly labelled as "remote sensor sensitivity" or something like that.

Comment: This is counterfeit because the corners are too rounded, compared to an original controller.

Comment: @Ecuador well, the sensitivity settings wouldn't work anyway ;)

Comment: @Ecuador: Yeah, the "sensor bar" is actually a complete misnomer.  The actual sensors are all in the WiiMote itself.  All you need is 4 lights.  I saw somebody had a setup with 4 candles and it worked perfectly.  I also had a similar experience with the recessed lighting in one apartment I lived in working in the same way.

Comment: Other than the answers, the quality and type of the plastic on the controller looks cheap too. Real ones are a bit glossier, and unlike a plastic-glossiness, they look like glass.

Comment: Good question and supporting media, entirely answerable and on-topic.  Rules-pedantry not required (or useful) here.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate: Companies tend to optimize production costs and later models often are more cheaply made than early ones. Sometimes even some features are missing, eg some settings being deemed as unimportant as nobody really used them. Just because it feels "worse" than the early one doesn't necessarily mean it's fake.

Comment: Someone involved with trading, repairing or modifying such remote controllers (not me unfortunately) could very well give a qualified answer.

Comment: Depending on the packaging/description this might not be "Counterfeit". Depending on what it was advertised and packaged as. It may just be an unofficial version.

Comment: I made my answer a community wiki and included answers from others. I won't get the rep, but we'll all have a better answer.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It's **definitely** not an official Nintendo remote, unless there's a regional manufacturing difference I'm unaware of.

**There's no Wii logo!**

Do a Google image search for "wii remote" and look at the bottom.

It is not "counterfeit". If it were, it would have the Wii logo.

Comment: oh wow I can't believe everyone missed this, the most definitive proof in all the answers here for sure.

Comment: Don't have a controller at hand.. is the "Wii" label: a sticker? Serigraphy? Etched into the plastic? Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Roflo i don't have one at hand either, but i know for sure it's not a sticker. not sure if it's etched or what, but as i best remember, the surface of the wiimote is entirely smooth over and around the logo. it's not something that could easily be scraped off (if even at all), in other words. also, Aequitas, the screws are definitive proof as well.

Comment: I don't believe I missed this! I was looking at the model number markings, the nintendo on the battery cover (there was one) and other minor things, but I forgot about that huge logo! If you put it next to the genuine controller it is really obvious, but I completely forgot!

Comment: @Reaces there's a difference between a 3rd party controller that's sold to work with the Wii, but doesn't pretend to be an official first party controller; and a counterfeit that puts all the logos on and pretends to be an official first party Nintendo controller.

Comment: @Reaces the answer's pretty clear to me. The first sentence clearly says, "It's definitely not an official Nintendo remote". That last sentence is just clarifying the difference between 3rd party (or off-brand) and counterfeit.

Comment: @reaces on this site, each answer stands alone. if you want to change or elaborate on an answer, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 67):

First tip is actually the screws.

[Article from IGN on Wiimote disassembly](http://www.ign.com/articles/2006/11/22/nintendo-wii-remote-dissection)

The screws are suppose to be triwings (Y shaped), and one needs a special screwdriver for them.  The fact that they are using standard Philips screws seems to indicate a counterfeit.

Comment: This seems pretty conclusive to me

Comment: I noticed that, but it was not bought "new" so somebody could claim it is the refurbishment process. But it is one more indicator I guess.

Comment: Couldn't this also just indicate that the screws had been replaced? It's most likely that it's fake, but not necessarily conclusive.

Comment: If it's a factory (Nintendo) authorized refurbishment shop, the shop should have access to the custom parts and tools and use those Y-shaped screws. In fact, the linked article indicates they're not unreasonably difficult to come by.

Comment: If the shop can take off the original Y screws, they can put it back in.  The alternatives in taking off the screws is to drill them out, but this prevents reassembly.

Comment: @nelson you can still reassemble it if you've carefully drilled it out, you'll only need a slightly bigger screw, it's plastic so rethreading would be easy with any type of screw tip

Answer (score 39):

All evidence suggests...

## It's most definitely a counterfeit (or an unlicensed generic brand)

#### External clues

- [First tip](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246129/131644) is actually **the screws** (see this [article from IGN on Wiimote disassembly](http://www.ign.com/articles/2006/11/22/nintendo-wii-remote-dissection): The screws are suppose to be Y shaped, and you were suppose to need a special screw driver for them.  The fact that they are using standard Philips screws seems to indicate a counterfeit (as [T.J.L.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/125677/t-j-l) said, an authorized refurbishment shop should have access to the tools for those Y-shaped screws).
- [Another very noticable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246248/131644) tip is that **there's no Wii logo!** If you do a Google image search for "wii remote" and look at the bottom.
- [If you check the plastic parts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/246207/131644) you'll notice the **absence of the "Nintendo" legend**. If you look at a official wiimote it will say Nintendo on each of the plastic case parts. This absence of the word Nintendo marks it as a counterfeit immediately. It may still function correctly but it is not an official wiimote.

#### Internal clues

From a hardware design point of view, there are a few clues that may be extracted. This is a breakdown of the main differences of the PCB (ie: the green board) with a [new controller](http://wiibrew.org/w/images/a/a1/Wii_Remote_uncovered.jpg) (image is [apparently copyrighted](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/File:Wii_Remote_uncovered.jpg), so it's not being included here).

1. **The main components** (ie: the black chips soldered to the green board) are very different. The ones in your controller are smaller, and although it's hard to make out the manufacturer it's not far fetched to assume they're cheaper than the "official" ones, which are from [well known](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#Input_Features) and [trusted](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#Accelerometer) manufacturers.
2. **Silkscreen** (ie: the white labels printed on top of the green board) are different in engineering practices. Your picture shows a very basic silkscreen use: it just says which component is which. In the image I linked above, silkscreen use follows a much more professional use (arrows for pin identification, label areas, indications for testing).
3. **Individual serial number / manufacturing id**. On the image I linked to, there's a silkscreen rectangle to the left, where a number is marked with black ink. A truly professional company (like one expects Nintendo to be) will mark each individual controller when assembled. This allows to track every single controller together with the PCB's serial markings in silkscreen.

#### Functionality

1. **Sensor bar sensitivity**. If you try to adjust the remote's sensor bar sensitivity from the Wii options, nothing really happens. From settings 1 to 5 the "dot" display will remain exactly the same, as counterfeit controllers seem to cut some corners in their IR sensor logic.

In conclusion, your images don't seem to be from a product that's supposed to have all sorts of certifications, be manufactured in several locations, be sold worldwide, and be supported globally in proper way.

Comment: Thanks. The most visible difference is that huge capacitor that your image has. AFAIK for capacitors size does matter, right? ;)

Comment: @Ecuador sure, maybe. But I wouldn't be 100% sure. There _might_ be a manufacturer that has a smaller capacitor with much better characteristics than a bigger counterpart (would be more expensive, of course).

Comment: Why have you included information from other answers? I've already read the ones above and don't need to read it twice.

Comment: @MartinSmith This answer is a **community wiki** answer, a very useful feature of SE sites. You can read more about it in [this page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki).

Comment: I'm aware of the concept of community wiki. I've been on StackExchange for nearly 7 years. I don't find repeating information from existing answers on the same page useful whether the answer is CW or not though.

Comment: @MartinSmith Well there are several points in this answer not included elsewhere. And perhaps this would work better if this was the answer on top but since it hasn't had voters and the OP didn't accept it, we can only wonder.

Comment: It's as much a counterfeit Wii controller as a Michelin tyre is a counterfeit Goodyear, or a Dell a counterfeit IBM PC. Making compatible products is not counterfeiting.

Comment: @PeteKirkham It is if you claim it's a refurbished but original brand. Michelin would never claim it sells refurbished Goodyears.

Comment: @Roflo that's the point. Pirelli tyres are a compatible replacement for Goodyear - the company which invented vulcanising technology. There is no evidence that the manufacturer of this controller is trying to pass it off as genuine Nintendo. The system is described as refurbished; if you buy a refurbished laptop the refurbisher might put in another brand of disk drive than was there originally, or a second hand car won't have the original brand of tyres. That doesn't remotely imply counterfeiting.

Comment: @PeteKirkham You know, I just took for granted that the OP had been sold a refurbished _Nintendo_ controller (had to reread the question carefully). Anyway, I did a minor edit to the opening title to reflect the counterfeit/unlicensed difference.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at a official wiimote it will say Nintendo on each of the plastic case parts. It may be due to the quality of your photos but I do not see the brand name anywhere on it. This absence of the word Nintendo marks it as a counterfeit immediately. It may still function correctly but it is not an official wiimote.

Comment: IMO, this is the best, simplest answer.  Companies tend to always brand things _because_ their name is a trademark that can't be copied.

Comment: @JPhi1618 `s/can't/isn't allowed to/` but that never stopped counterfitters

Comment: @ratchetfreak right, but "3rd party" products like the one pictured are obvious because of the missing name.

Comment: The brand name being present doesn't prove a widget *isn't* counterfeit, but the brand name being *absent* proves that it *is* counterfeit (assuming the real thing is branded, as we know Wiimotes are).

Comment: @zwol i would stress the difference between *counterfeit* and *knock-off* brand ... it's perfectly legal to manufacture third-party wii remotes, so i wouldn't call the one in the question a "counterfeit". it's just an off-brand that someone sold to OP, trying to pass off as the real thing. if it were a true counterfeit, it would HAVE the wii logo.

Comment: @sgroves Fair point.